# Git SourceTree trvs

Tags: ios, git, atlassian-sourcetree

I work with iOS and I use sourcetree for managing my git. Sometimes SourceTree (git?) creates files with *trvs* extensions. Usually the files are the same as original ones but sometimes they slightly differ.
What are *trvs* files?

Comment: This shouldn't be linked to Git or SourceTree. Maybe it is related to a third-party tool (like https://github.com/travisjeffery/TRVSMonitor)?

Comment: I dont use TRVSMonitor. I checked all my third-party tools and I dont think they affect my git, however i am not 100% sure.

Comment: Can you pinpoint the exact circumstance when a tsvr is created? Or is it completely random?

Comment: I would say its not entirely random because it happens more often on merges.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. It was clang formatter installed via alcatraz. Reinstalled everything again and it works fine.